# Only directory listing in cakephp setup

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I have a Cakephp backup and I want to setup it on my local xampp setup. I backup it from the server in which it is running smoothly. When I want to open using localhost, it displaying the /app/webroot/ directory listing.

I am using windows 7 with xampp. I started mod_rewrite already.

my .htaccess file has

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
   DirectoryIndex /front/default.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong in your document. Your .htaccess should like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: I pasted the root .htaccess file. /app/webroot has the <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I used this but now blank page is displayed.

Comment: See updated code now. What is location of above .htaccess file?